# Strange error on exit mail from hpux

Tags: sendmail, mailx

My HP-UX mailer works fine; I can reach machines and send emails
and also delete.
But on exit from `mailx`, after deleting messages, I get

```
rmmail: cannot unlink /var/mail/myuser
```

Why?

My permissions (sendmail runs as "sendmail" user)

```
$ ls -lhd /var/mail/
drwxrwxr-t 2 root sendmail 96  18 mar 18.41 /var/mail/
$ ls -lhd /var/mail/user
-rw-rw---- 1 user sendmail  0  18 mar 18.42 /var/mail/user
```

Comment: could you please edit your question and update with the output of this command: `ls -ld /var/mail/myuser*` ?

Comment: 660 for all user:mail permission,sendmail run as "mail" user

Comment: `user` does not have write permissions on the `/var/mail` directory, so the attempt to remove that entry from the directory fails. Only `root` or an account in the `sendmail` group would be able to change the directory.

Comment: Yes,i have to use 1777,only for dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

```
chmod 1777 /var/mail
```